# Java verifying an enum value passed as an argument

Tags: java, junit, enums

I have the following enum

```
public enum State {
    UNCHECKED, SUBMITTED, VALIDATED, REJECTED, ENTITLED;
}
```

and in another class I have a method that receives a State as an argument, like this

```
public void validate (State state) throws InvalidStateException {
    if (state != State.VALIDATED || state != State.REJECTED) 
        throw new InvalidStateException(); 
}
```

this method should throw the exception InvalidStateException only when the argument State isn't either State.VALIDATED or State.REJECTED but is in fact throwing it always.
I just can't see where the mistake can be or how could I write the code in another way that would work.

I know that this isn't working because the following JUnit Test says the mentioned exception is being thrown and it shouldn't:

```
@Test
public void testValidate () throws InvalidStateException {
    object.validate(State.VALIDATED);
}
```

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||` on your IF!

Answer (score 2):

The condition `state != State.VALIDATED || state != State.REJECTED` is always true. the only way for it to be false would be for state to be VALIDATED and REJECTED at the same time.

You want `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that last night! When I corrected it everything went perfectly. Thanks